# Python / Kivy / Gif : How to remove gif after animation

Tags: python, kivy, gif, animated-gif

I want to have a Gif as an opening animation that is deleted or moved away after the animation. However nothing seems to work, the image just stays there.

```
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivymd.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.extras.highlight import KivyLexer
from kivy.lang.parser import ParserException
from kivy.properties import ColorProperty
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

import time
import threading
import random

kv = ("""   
FloatLayout:
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'test_back.png'

    Image:
        id: intro
        source: 'test_anim.gif'
        size_hint: None, None
        size: "500dp", "500dp"
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.5}
        allow_stretch: False
        anim_delay: 0.05
        anim_loop: 1

""")

class testApp(App):
    def build(self):
        kivy_design = Builder.load_string(kv)
        self.app_root = kivy_design
        return kivy_design

    def on_start(self):
        frame_counter = 0
        frame_counter += 1
        if frame_counter == 30:
            self.app_root.ids.intro.pos_hint = {'center_x':-.5, 'center_y':-.5}

testApp().run()
```

I tried now for quite some time and also looked at other similar issues like this.

What am I missing? Thanks for reading

Comment: If you use screens then just move to another screen after some specified duration. Here you can simply remove the image widget after your defined duration of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can schedule the removal of the `intro`, and keep delaying that removal until the `gif` stops. Here is a modified version of your code that does that:

```
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import App

kv = ("""   
FloatLayout:
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'test_back.png'

    Image:
        id: intro
        source: 'test_anim.gif'
        size_hint: None, None
        size: "500dp", "500dp"
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.5}
        allow_stretch: False
        anim_delay: 0.05
        anim_loop: 1
        on_texture: app.texture_updated()  # this lets us know every frame

""")

class testApp(App):
    def build(self):
        kivy_design = Builder.load_string(kv)
        self.app_root = kivy_design
        return kivy_design

    def on_start(self):
        # schedule removal of intro gif
        self.remove_it = Clock.schedule_once(self.remove_gif, self.root.ids.intro.anim_delay * 2)

    def texture_updated(self):
        # gif has been updated, so cancel removal
        self.remove_it.cancel()

        # reschedule removal
        self.remove_it = Clock.schedule_once(self.remove_gif, self.root.ids.intro.anim_delay * 2)

    def remove_gif(self, dt):
        # actually remove the intro gif
        self.root.remove_widget(self.root.ids.intro)



testApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the coded answer will be, but the theory could be that you find the length of the GIF. Play the GIF on a page and set the time for display for the length of the GIF then just display another page with what you want afterwards.